# How to load data into a vuex module only when it's needed? problems with async/await

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, async-await, vuex

Is there a way to load all the data for a vuex store once but only load it if it's needed?

I assume there is but i'm struggling and i'm not sure if it's because i'm misunderstanding Vuex or Async/Await in Javascript promises.

This an example store for `Roles`. The `userRolesApi` makes an axios request and returns a promise.

```
import {userRolesApi} from "../api";

export default {
    actions: {
        setRoles(context, roles) {
            context.commit('SET_ROLES', roles)
        },
        async loadRoles({state, dispatch}) {
            if (state.all === null) {
                return await userRolesApi.index().then(response => {
                    dispatch('setRoles', response.data)
                })
            }
        }
    },
    state: {
        all: null
    },
    getters: {
        findRoleFromId: (state) => (role) => {
            return _.find(state.all, {id: parseInt(role)})
        },
        findRoleFromName: (state) => (role) => {
            return _.find(state.all, {name: role})
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_ROLES (state, roles) {
            state.all = roles
        },
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is call `findRoleFromId` from within a Vue Component.

That would then get the role from the roles array in state `state.all`, but also build that array from the API if it doesn't already exist.

From what I can tell it's bad practice to make api requests from inside getters so instead i've got the `loadRoles` method in an action instead.

But I can't call an action from a getter so now i'm going to have to call `loadRoles` from somewhere else, everytime I think I might need to use a role.

So I wind up with a component like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles')
},
computed: {
    role() {
        // This will be null at first but update once the api request finishes.
        return this.$store.getters.findRoleFromId(this.roleId)
    }
},
```

This actually works perfectly!

However if for some reason I call `this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles')` in two components in quick succession then it will make the api request twice.

I've attempted to resolve this using async/await but it doesn't seem to matter, it doesn't stop processing until the request is finished.

As a test changing my component to this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles')
},
computed: {
    role() {
        return this.$store.getters.findRoleFromId(this.roleId)
    }
},
```

Causes the api request to be called 4 times instantly. Rather than waiting for the first one to finish and then on the second attempt failing the `state.all === null` check and not making the api request.

I've tried to be as verbose as possible in explaining what it is i'm trying to do because i'm not actually sure where it is i'm going wrong. From that my questions are:

1. What is the best way to populate a vuex store only when it's needed?
2. If my approach is a good way to do it, what's wrong with my attempt at async/await?

Answer (score 0):

Your components should not care about how many times they request a resource, neither should the userRolesApi I think. If eventually you use fetch then you can cache the promise as long as it's not resolved or rejected and later requests will just return that promise.

```
const fetchOnce = ((cache) => (url, config) => {
    const cacheKey = `${JSON.stringify(config)} ${url}`;
    if (!cache[cacheKey]) {
        cache[cacheKey] = axios.get(url, config)
            .then((result) => {
                delete cache[cacheKey];
                return result;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                delete cache[cacheKey];
                return Promise.reject(error);
            });
    }
    return cache[cacheKey];
})({});
```

Comment: Where exactly does this fetchOnce happen?

And where is `cache` is that in the vuex store state or somewhere else?

Also in your answer if the first request hasn't finished then it will still have the problem of the cache being empty and making the call again.

Comment: @JohnMellor  `if the first request hasn't finished ... call again` => no it won't. You'd call fetchOnce where you would normally call fetch and the cache is passed in to the IIFE that returns a function with the same signature as fetch.

Comment: Is there an equivalent with axios rather than having to switch everything to fetch?

Comment: @JohnMellor Updated the answer using `axios.get`

Comment: Also, (just out of interest) any reason you are using `return Promise.reject(error)` instead of just `throw error`?

Comment: As you are using axios, you might have a look here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/31

Comment: @EuanSmith I'd think returning `Promise.reject(error)` and `throw error` would probably be the same. Not sure if a linter would complain when you try to throw something that may or may not be an error.

Comment: @EuanSmith It is not caching anything at the moment. Only bundling unfinished requests that are the same.